# Remove trailing slash from urls - Go static server

Tags: http, go, server, go-http, go-server

I've set up a simple Go static file server with `http.FileServer`. If I have a directory structure like `public > about > index.html`, the server will correctly resolve `/about` to `about > index.html`, but it adds a trailing slash so the url becomes `/about/`.

Is there a simple way to remove these trailing slashes when using `http.FileServer`? Ultimately, it works either way - it's mostly just a personal preference to not have the trailing slashes if possible.

Comment: It's not a personal preference. An URL's pathname ending in `/` tells the server the client wants a representation representing the list of resources available at that path, while a pathname not ending in `/` asks the server to send the representation of a particular entity at that path.

Comment: ([More info](http://sebastians-pamphlets.com/the-anatomy-of-http-redirects-301-302-307/#invisible-server-redirects), with references to relevant material.)

Comment: @kostix that could be a convention for _some_ but it's certainly not in any HTTP standard documents

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a rare case where Go is arbitrarily opinionated about something and hard-coded that opinion into the stdlib. There is no way to "fix" it while using `http.FileServer`.

Comment: @Adrian you can actually work around this by registering two explicit routes.

Comment: @colm.anseo yes, *if you don't use* `FileServer` for one of them. So, as I said - there is not way to fix this **while using** `http.FileServer`.

Comment: @Adrian your comment gave the impression that this was a dead-end from the Go `stdlib` perspective. But the OP can work around this by working with `http.ServeMux`.

Answer (score 1):

When you register the route `/about/` an implicit route of `/about` is added (which redirects clients to `/about/`).

To work around this, you can register two explicit routes:

- `/about` to serve your `index.html`
- `/about/` to serve the `http.FileServer` to handle any HTML assets for the page

like so:

```
// what you had before
h.Handle("/about/",
    http.StripPrefix(
        "/about/",
        http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp/about-files")),
    ),
)

// prevents implicit redirect to `/about/`
h.HandleFunc("/about",
    func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "index.html") // serves a single file from this route
    },
)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/WLwLPV5WuJm